# Error installing devstack

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, openstack

I am trying to install DevStack following the tutorial from [here](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/openstack-savanna-fast-hadoop)

It says I have to run `./stack.sh` as non-root user and I did. But I am getting this error.

```
++ [[ -n False ]]
++ [[ False != \F\a\l\s\e ]]
++ date +%s
/home/mani/devstack/tools/install_prereqs.sh: line 80: /home/mani/devstack/.prereqs: Permission denied
+++ err_trap
+++ local r=1
+++ set +o xtrace
stack.sh failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running ./create-stack-user.sh, try this

```
chown -R stack:stack /opt/devstack(the path of the cloned devstack) 
su stack 
./stack.sh .
```

I've stuck with the same problem and this worked..!!

Comment: Thanks!! I'm hitting a wall every few minutes, but this solved my current issue. On my install, it was cloned to /etc/devstack, so I just changed the path and it worked. Sweet!!

Answer (score 1):

Your error `stack.sh failed with Permission denied`

This will fix for centos 7x

```
cd /opt/
chmod 755 stack
cd stack
chmod 755 devstack
```

Answer (score 0):

The user must still be in the sudoers file. So add the username while root run the command `visudo` and add the user name what ever it is under root ALL=(ALL) ALL

so you will have:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
newuserX ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

re-run ./stack.sh as regular user (with sudo permissions)

might want to clean any previous install attempts with ./clean.sh first, before re-install

Comment: Just to clarify your very good answer. When you write the newuserX try to put the name of the user that you will use to execute the stack.sh

In that case stack user.